# How do i use kattio in java to get line

Tags: java, string, io, line, spacing

how do I get line using kattio
eg.
hello a
hello b
I understand that String s = io.getWord(); will return me hello but I want to obtain hello a

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in kattio that lets tyou do this, at all. My suggestion: Don't use it at all, there is nothing in it that you can't do better and easier with basic java tooling.

For example, with scanner:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
s.useDelimiter("\\R");

// and now it's ready, just:

String line = s.next();
int number = s.nextInt();
double v = s.nextDouble();
```

does exactly what you want given as input:

```
hello a b
20
18.21871287
```